# Remove srcset attribute for cart-item-thumbnail-image on woocommerce cart page

Tags: woocommerce

Testing the cart page cross-browser I noticed that the cart-item-thumbnail image disappears on some instances, when adding, removing items or altering addresses on the cart page.
I found out, that the presence of the srcset attribute is causing this.
I tried to disable the srcset attribute for the cart page like so:

```
        function cart_disable_srcset() {
            if ( is_cart()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        add_filter( 'wp_calculate_image_srcset', 'cart_disable_srcset' );
```

The codition `if ( is_cart())` is ignored, and the srcset is removed site-wide.

Then I found a function, that removes the srcset for `the_post_thumbnail( 'full' )` and
`the_post_thumbnail()`:

```
        /**
         * Remove the srcset attribute from post thumbnails 
         * that are called with the 'full' size string: the_post_thumbnail( 'full' )
         *
         * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/214071/26350
         */
         add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_size', function( $size )
         {
             if( is_string( $size ) && 'full' === $size )
                 add_filter( 
                     'wp_calculate_image_srcset_meta',  
                      '__return_null_and_remove_current_filter' 
                 );   
            return $size;
         } );

        // Would be handy, in this example, to have this as a core function ;-)
        function __return_null_and_remove_current_filter ( $var )
        {
            remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
            return null;
        }
```

In my cart.php template if have the following line:

```php
$thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image('my_small_size'), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

I tried to use this with the function mentioned above:

```
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', function( $size )
         {
             if( is_string( $size ) && 'my_small_size' === $size )
                 add_filter( 
                     'wp_calculate_image_srcset_meta',  
                      '__return_null_and_remove_current_filter' 
                 );   
            return $size;
         } );
```

But that doesn’t bear the desired result.

How can I configure the above mentioned function to remove the srcset for the cart-item-thumbnail and all other images that are referenced with `my_small_size`? Can this be achieved at all with this function, or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Hook into `wp_calculate_image_srcset` read: [detailed explanation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291895/how-to-exclude-an-image-size-from-the-wordpress-srcset).
`$source` is an array that holds all images for the `srcset` attribute.
The custom image size 65*65, which is displayed on my cart-page, can be found by conditionally checking the `$size_array`. If the `$size_array` has 65, then unset all unwanted sizes.
The `srcset` is gone. No more vanishing cart-item-thumbnails when altering the cart page items on certain browsers. The rest is configuring the `srcset` according to my needs. It may be helpful as an example.

```
    add_filter( 'wp_calculate_image_srcset', 'my_custom_image_srcset', 10, 5);

    function my_custom_image_srcset($sources, $size_array, $image_src, $image_meta, $attachment_id) {
            //remove unwanted sizes from $source array
            $remove = ['150', '300'];
            $sources = array_diff_key($sources, array_flip($remove));

            //remove unwanted sizes from $source array if thumbnail width is 65
            if ($size_array[0] === 65){
                $remove = ['160', '490','768','800'];
                $sources = array_diff_key($sources, array_flip($remove));
            }

            //remove unwanted sizes for archive pages
            else if (is_archive()){
                $remove = ['65', '768','800'];
                $sources = array_diff_key($sources, array_flip($remove));
            }

            //remove unwanted sizes for product pages
            else if (is_product()){
                $remove = ['65', '160'];
                $sources = array_diff_key($sources, array_flip($remove));
            } 
            
            //check results
            //print_r($size_array);
            //print_r($sources);
            return $sources;
        }
```

Unfortunately nobody commented the function mentioned in the question.
But this hook works for me.

Comment: This is not working.